# Dadas 2 listas generar 2 nuevas listas con los elementos que estan en ambas y con los que estan solo en una

Tags: c++, c++11

Dadas dos listas ordenadas **L1** y **L2**, escribir una función:

```
void bool_opers(list<int> &Lxor, list<int> &Land, list<int> &L1, list<int> &L2);
```

El algoritmo debe generar en ***Lxor*** una nueva lista ordenada con todos los elementos que estén en sólo una de las dos listas originales, y en ***Land*** una nueva lista ordenada con todos los elementos que estén
en ambas.

Por ejemplo, si **L1=(1,3,5,7,9)** y **L2=(3,4,5,6,7)**, entonces el algoritmo debe generar las listas

***Lxor=(1,4,6,9)*** y ***Land=(3,5,7)***.

El codigo al que llegue es el siguiente:

```
auto it=L1.begin();
  while(it != L1.end()) {
    auto it2=L2.begin();
    bool flag = false;
    while(it2 != L2.end()){
      if(*it == *it2) {
        Land.push_back(*it);
        it = L1.erase(it);
        it2 = L2.erase(it2);
        --it; --it2;
      }
      ++it2;

    }
    ++it;
  }
  Lxor.insert(Lxor.begin(), L1.begin(), L1.end());
  Lxor.insert(Lxor.end(), L2.begin(), L2.end());
  Lxor.sort();
```

Parece funcionar en la mayoria de los casos. El problema es que pruebo este codigo en una funcion evaluadora que usan los profesores de mi clase de algoritmos y estructura de datos y entra en un bucle infinito. Esta funcion lo que hace es probar el codigo con muchos casos y decir si esta correcto o no. Yo no puedo ver los casos con los que se prueba por eso no se donde estoy fallando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `erase` (disponible en muchos contenedores de datos, no se cuál estarás usando) devuelve el iterador posterior al borrado (o `end` si ha borrado el último). En tu algoritmo tras borrar un dato, retrocedes una posición y en ese caso si has borrado el último dato: ya no saldrás de bucle.

Partiendo de un estado en que a ambas listas les quede un sólo elemento, siendo este elemento repetido en ambas:

---

[image]

---

Cuando borras, haces que ambos iteradores apunten a `end`.

---

[image]

---

Acto seguido, rebobinas ambos iteradores, haciendo que apunten a un lugar desconocido; dependiendo del [tipo de iterador [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) esto tendrá malas, malísimas o peores consecuencias; posiblemente los nuevos iteradores (apuntando a un lugar desconocido) ya no serán capaces de rastrear su posición y moverlos provocará más problemas.

---

[image]

---

Lo siguiente que haces es avanzar `it2`, el cuál (al estar perdido) no avanza correctamente y no alcanza nunca `end`, entrando en un bucle infinito ya que por mucho que lo sigas avanzando, posiblemente no alcance el final de nuevo.

---

[image]

---

#### Propuesta.

Estás complicando mucho el código, te aconsejo utilizar una aproximación que no sea agresiva con la listas (no modifique las listas) y centrar las decisiones en si un valor está o no presente, yo lo haría así:

```
using enteros = std::list<int>;

std::pair<enteros, enteros> bool_opers(const enteros &L1, const enteros &L2)
{
    enteros repetidos, unicos;

    // Una sencilla lambda que devuelve 'true' si el valor está en la lista
    auto esta = [](int valor, const enteros &lista)
    {
        return std::find(lista.begin(), lista.end(), valor) != lista.end();
    };

    // Si un valor de L1 está en L2: es repetido. En caso contrario es único.
    for (const auto &valor : L1)
        if (esta(valor, L2))
            repetidos.push_back(valor);
        else
            unicos.push_back(valor);
    // Ya sabemos los repetidos entre L1 y L2, sólo buscamos los L2 que no están en L1
    for (const auto &valor : L2)
        if (!esta(valor, L1))
            unicos.push_back(valor);

    return {repetidos, unicos};
}
```

Comment: El problema es que en las listas puede haber valores repetidos. Por ejemplo **L1 = [1,3,4,6]**, **L2 = [2,4,4,4,5]** en ese caso en la lista de los repetidos apareceria el 4 varias veces. Y en realidad tendria que haber un solo 4 en la lista de los repetidos y dos 4 en la lista de los que estan solo en una de las dos listas iniciales.

Comment: No veo en tu pregunta que lo menciones en ningún sitio. Pero no pasa nada, tan sólo aplica [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) sobre la lista de repetidos antes de devolverla.